# Salesforce Files for massive storage

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, file-storage

One of my clients have a requirement where they want to upload thousands of files everyday in Salesforce. I did some rough calculations and looks like they'll be adding roughly 1 TB of files every year in their Org. They are okay paying the additional storage cost.

I want to know are there any other considerations with using Salesforce for storing that huge no. of documents?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are three main considerations: the cost, the technical limits, and the lead time.

Adding anything with salesforce.com typically requires a contract to be signed every time you do anything. So even adding 167x500MB storage blocks a month isn't as simple as it appears; it often takes days or longer to get a feature added to your org. Due to this, your client would have to be constantly planning ahead to make sure they don't run over their data cap. Salesforce does have a grace period before it blocks new files, but it's pretty slim.

The only way to make it work without too much hassle would be to buy the blocks annually. The public pricing is $125/month/500MB, which means you're looking at 2,000 storage blocks annually with a potential total cost of $250,000... a month. And that's just the first year. By year four, you're looking at an addon cost of $12,000,000. Even if they have really deep pockets, I'm sure they have other things they'd rather spend that kind of money on.

In addition, there are the [technical limits](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.content_file_size_limits.htm&type=5). You're limited to 30,000,000 files, 2,000 file libraries, 2GB per file, 50GB of bandwidth per day, and a maximum of 200,000 files/versions per day. If you're talking about 1TB a year, some of these limits realistically sound like Salesforce Content just isn't for your client.

Storing the actual data in Salesforce isn't really scalable the way your client envisions. Content is designed for, and meant to be used as, a way to distribute things like marketing and training materials, not storing anything and everything. AWS, Box, Dropbox, or any other service that specializes in file storage would be better than trying to it all in Salesforce. Salesforce is great at a lot of things but is definitely prohibitive as a general file storage system.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox! That is amazingly helpful

Comment: @Maneesh - remember to mark the answer as accepted